# Version of tensorflow for Labview Imaq DL

Tags: tensorflow, keras, labview

I descover that Version of tensorflow for Labview Imaq DL is:
tensorflow 1.4.0 on windows with numpy 1.4.1, python 3.6.8 and keras 2.1.5

I hope it's help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: It's a no question, but a configuration for helps.

Comment: I discovered recently that correct version is tf 1.4.0 and keras 2.0.8 on windows. Tf 1.4.1 and keras 2.1.5 on linux. Sorry for it.